# Redirect unauthenticated user nuxt js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have the following code snippet in my `middleware/auth.js`

```js
export default function ({ store, router }) {
  if (!store.state.admin.isAdmin) {
    router.push({ path: '/auth/login' })
  }
}
```

I want to redirect any unauthenticated users to login page. With the above code I'm getting error of:

**Cannot read property 'push' of undefined**

How do I access router properties in middleware so that I can redirect users ?

Comment: Does [this](https://nuxtjs.org/examples/auth-routes/) help?

Comment: Use `route` instead `router `

Comment: @Mohsen how can I prevent authenticated users from accessing the login page. Redirect them to dashboard. Here is the closest replica of the app.

https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-jackson-wkfuj?file=/pages/index.vue

Comment: There are many ways to implement it, another way is use page middleware https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-middleware

Comment: @Mohsen thanks but here lies the issue. Initial value of authenticated in state is false, so   middleware takes that value. I'm calling a commit function on mounted method in default layout for data persistence on refresh. Is there a way to to redirect after the commit is made on state ?

Comment: You can return promise in commit and redirect in `then` method or use async function await for commit result

Comment: @Mohsen I found another intresting thing. I've posted here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64131342/redirect-authenticated-users-nuxt-js

Answer (score 1):

This is my `middleware/auth.js`:

```
export default function ({ app, redirect }) {
    if (process.client) {
        if (!app.$auth.loggedIn) {
            redirect('/login');
        }
    }
}
```